# Multiplier algebra of direct sum of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras. Is it true that
$$M(A \oplus B) = M(A) \oplus M(B)$$
Since the direct sum of double centralizers of $A$ and $B$ gives a double centralizer of $A \oplus B$, we should get an injection
$$M(A) \oplus M(B) \hookrightarrow M(A \oplus B)$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Specifically, I would like to compute the multiplier algebra of $\mathcal K \oplus \mathcal K$ where $\mathcal K$ are the compact operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. More generally, we have
$$M\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i \right)= \bigoplus_{i\in I}^{\ell^\infty} M(A_i)$$
where the direct sum on the left can be interpreted as either a $c_0$ or an $\ell^\infty$-direct sum and on the right we have the $\ell^\infty$-direct sum. See the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402383/direct-sum-of-multiplier-algebras).

In particular, if $H$ is a Hilbert space, you have
$$M(\mathcal{K}(H)\oplus \mathcal{K}(H)) = B(H)\oplus B(H)\subseteq B(H\oplus H).$$